fitting skeleton to mesh after using shape keys in three js?
i have this human model from makehuman addon in blender. i imported using gltfloader, and the shape keys and the rest works great. The problem is that when adjust the mesh with shape keys, the skeleton stays at the same position.
chatgpt suggests calculating the offset between base position and morphed positions of vertices, and move each bone by that offset. there are a lot of shape keys and the skeleton has over 900 bones, so i thought maybe there's a more efficient way of doing this. What kind of approach do you recommend?
video: https://imgur.com/a/6UsBm2P
